# Is SSMS check constraint editor broken?

Tags: ssms

If I type this into the expression box:

```
1=0 OR (1=1 AND 2=2)
```

It will change it when I save it and then when I open it again it comes out like this:

```
((1)=(0) OR (1)=(1) AND (2)=(2))
```

which reduces down to...

```
1=0 OR 1=1 AND 2=2
```

which is clearly different than my original expression. What gives?

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio: 11.0.5058.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` is evaluated before `OR`, so both expressions would actually give the same result.

I imagine that is taken into account when the expression is processed and stored and so influences the resulting/stored expression.

Comment: Apparently I've been using parentheses religiously enough that I've never noticed this